# Connect ESP32 and a W5500 to an STM Blue Pill, doable?

Tags: stm32, ethernet, esp32

I am looking for a way to give my project both WLAN and LAN but because I need all the IO pins on an ESP32 (which may also be a bit too slow for my application) I can't just use a LAN module on the ESP.

My thought was to use the ESP as a WLAN receiver and a W5500 as LAN receiver and connect them both over SPI to an STM Blue Pill  or some other microcontroller that is a bit stronger.

Now I would like to know if that is practical and doable or if you guys may have any other ideas.

Comment: w5500 can give you ethernet and esp32 wireless fidelity(wi-fi). You can decide if it is doable now.

Comment: which blue pill do you refer to? The usual stm32f103 is hardly stronger than one of the cores in an ESP32. ESP32 spi to the W5500 should achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESP-Hosted might help with the WiFi Interface between the MCU and ESP32.

It uses SPI to transmit data between processors
https://github.com/espressif/esp-hosted

Adafruit has a similar interface, but it uses 2 extra pins
https://github.com/ladyada/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ESP32SPI

I'm sorry I can't help you with your hardware without a schematic, and even then my expertise is more in software. Please let me know if I can help in any way!